# UnsatisfiedLinkError with JavaCV Android

Tags: android, eclipse, javacv

I am trying get JavaCV working for android in order to gain the use of the FFMPEG library. I'm following the setup instructions for android from the JavaCV [website](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) which I've copied below:

> Eclipse (Android 2.2 or newer):
> Follow the instructions on this page: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/
> Go to File > New > Folder, select your project as parent folder, type "libs/armeabi" as Folder name, and click Finish.
> Copy javacpp.jar and javacv.jar into the newly created "libs" folder.
> Extract all the *.so files from javacv-android-arm.jar, opencv-2.4.3-android-arm.zip, and ffmpeg-1.0-android-arm.zip directly into the newly created "libs/armeabi" folder, without creating any new subdirectories.
> Navigate to Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and click "Add JARs...".
> Select both javacpp.jar and javacv.jar from the newly created "libs" folder.

I am trying to use the FFmpegFrameGrabber class in my code. When I run, I get this error from logcat:

> 02-01 14:40:35.550: W/dalvikvm(11583): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/avutil;
>
> 02-01 14:40:35.550: W/dalvikvm(11583): Exception Ljava/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError; thrown while initializing Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/avcodec;
>
> 02-01 14:40:35.550: D/AndroidRuntime(11583): Shutting down VM
>
> 02-01 14:40:35.550: W/dalvikvm(11583): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

This led me to believe that my android app can't find avutil.so and avcodec.so, which I placed in the libs/armeabi folder. However, when I unzipped the APK eclipse generated, both so files were present.

Any ideas as to the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that would come across this problem, I've set up a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/vxhviet/cd39621ae768be07dca30e399c36c034) providing step by step instruction on how to set up JavaCV 1.1 on Android Studio 2.1.1.

This tut will use JavaCV 1.1, version 1.2 currently has [SIGSEGV issue](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/412). JavaCV 1.1 comes with FFmpeg 2.8.1.

1. Obtain the prebulit binaries [here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/bytedeco/javacv/1.1/javacv-1.1-bin.zip).
2. Extract it and copy these files:

   - *javacpp.jar* (**essential**).
   - *javacv.jar* (**essential**).
   - *ffmpeg.jar* (**essential if you use FFmpeg**).
   - *ffmpeg-android-arm.jar* (for arm CPU).
   - *ffmpeg-android-x86.jar* (optional for x86 CPU).
     into the `libs` folder of your project (`app/libs` in my case).
3. Click on `app` -> `F4` -> `Dependencies` -> `+` -> `File dependencies` -> choose all the previous *.jar*.
4. Temporarily, because of [this issue](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/245), we need to set `targetSdkVersion 22` the app's `build.gradle`.
5. Possibly need to set these `packagingOptions` in the `build.gradle`:

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.test"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/pom.xml'

    //might need these if you use openCV
    //exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/opencv/pom.properties'
    //exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/opencv/pom.xml'
}
```

}

Comment: Link only answers discouraged on stackoverflow. Please include essential parts of the solution in this post